# display rows as columns in mysql using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table

```
 create table course
 (
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    course_name varchar(50),
    level varchar(20),
    course_detail varchar(250)
 );



 insert into course(course_name,level,course_detail) values
 ('c','beginner','datatypes'),
 ('c','beginner','basics'),
 ('c','beginner','variables'),
 ('c','intermediate','functions'),
 ('c','intermediate','loops'),
 ('c','advanced','stacks'),
 ('c','advanced','queues'),

 ('java','beginner','datatypes'),
 ('java','beginner','basics'),
 ('java','beginner','variables'),
 ('java','intermediate','eventlisteners'),
 ('java','intermediate','exeptions'),
 ('java','advanced','jdbc'),
 ('java','advanced','j2ee');
```

Output should be like this:

```
course_name  beginner   intermediate     advanced
-------------------------------------------------
  c          basics     functions        stacks
  c          datatypes  loops            queues
  c          variables   
  java       basics     eventlisteners   jdbc
  java       datatypes  exceptions       j2ee
  java       variables
```

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Have you written any queries for this yet? Something along the lines of - `SELECT course_name, level, course_detail FROM course`. Are you using PDO or mysqli?

Comment: You got any code to get this output?

Comment: You can not have the exact same view with simple query which needs more complex query, however this is the simple way to achieve something similar http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/140d37/3

Comment: I'm sure INT*(4)* doesn't do whatever you think it does!

Comment: i have written one query   but i m not able to display the way i want to eliminate null values and display the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes MyISAM or that id is a surrogate PK, as per my edit above.

```
SELECT course_name
     , MAX(CASE WHEN level = 'beginner' THEN course_detail END) beginner
     , MAX(CASE WHEN level = 'intermediate' THEN course_detail END) intermediate
     , MAX(CASE WHEN level = 'advanced' THEN course_detail END) advanced
  FROM 
     (
       SELECT x.*
            , COUNT(*) rank 
         FROM course x 
         JOIN course y 
           ON y.course_name = x.course_name 
          AND y.level = x.level 
          AND y.id <= x.id 
        GROUP 
           BY course_name
            , id
     ) a
 GROUP 
    BY course_name,rank;
```